# Socket.io with Rabbitmq for one to one chat

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq

I'm building a one to one chat with Socket.io and RabbitMQ

My implementation of doing a one to one chat is working, but I'm not sure whether the implementation is correct or not.

1. `roomID` is equivalent to for example `42314`
2. the `roomID` is autogenerated when user matched with another user.
3. The logic is simple, user A join a room `42314` and it will emit to the server.
4. Once user A joined the room, he can send a message which emits the message from the client to the server.

   ```
   rabbit.connect("amqp://localhost", (connError, connection) => {
      connection.createChannel((channelError, channel) => {
         io.on("connection", (socket) => {
          // This is where user join the room
          // and the channel add a new queue which the room ID
            socket.on("join", (room) => {
              channel.assertQueue(room.roomID, {
                   durable: false,
              });
            socket.join(room.roomID);
          });

         // This is the part where user send message to another user
         socket.on("sendMessage", (room) => {
            // Once user send a message, it will send to the queue.
            channel.sendToQueue(room.roomID, Buffer.from(room.message));

           // since the queue has the room id, whenever there is a message
          // emit it to the room.
           channel.consume(
              room.roomID,
               (msg) => {
                  console.log(" Received " + msg.content.toString());

                  io.in(room.roomID).emit("message", msg.content.toString());
               },
               {
                noAck: true,
               }
             );
          });
        });
      });
    });
   ```

My questions are

1. Does my implementation correct?
2. Can this architecture work if there is a load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

1. I think using RabbitMQ adds unnecessary complications and lags. You can achieve this with just socket.io, when you receive message, you immediately emit to recipient

   ```
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
     // This is where user join the room
     // and the channel add a new queue which the room ID
     socket.on("join", (room) => {
       socket.join(room.roomID);
     });

     // This is the part where user send message to another user
     socket.on("sendMessage", (room) => {
     // Once user send a message, it will send to the queue.
     // channel.sendToQueue(room.roomID, Buffer.from(room.message));

     // since the queue has the room id, whenever there is a message
     // emit it to the room.
     io.in(room.roomID).emit("message", room.message);
     });
    });
   ```
2. You will need some sort of sticky session to have implementation work behind a load balancer. You can read more on how to achieve this [socket io using multiple nodes](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/)